# Javascript literal expressions

Tags: javascript

`"use strict"` - defines that `JavaScript` code should be executed in strict mode.

Is there any other `JavaScript` literal expressions similar to `"use strict";`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at the moment, no, `"use strict";` is unique.

The spec calls these "directives." They're part of a "directive prologue." Details [in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-directive-prologues-and-the-use-strict-directive):

> **Directive Prologues and the Use Strict Directive**
>
> A *Directive Prologue* is the longest sequence of *ExpressionStatement* productions occurring as the initial *StatementListItem* or *ModuleItem* productions of a *FunctionBody*, a *ScriptBody*, or a *ModuleBody* and where each *ExpressionStatement* in the sequence consists entirely of a *StringLiteral* token followed by a semicolon. The semicolon may appear explicitly or may be inserted by automatic semicolon insertion. A Directive Prologue may be an empty sequence.
>
> A *Use Strict Directive* is an *ExpressionStatement* in a Directive Prologue whose *StringLiteral* is either the exact code unit sequences  `"use strict"` or `'use strict'`. A Use Strict Directive may not contain an *EscapeSequence* or *LineContinuation*.
>
> A Directive Prologue may contain more than one Use Strict Directive. However, an implementation may issue a warning if this occurs.